# Haskell String list to Int list

Tags: haskell

I have a list of strings and I want to read the strings one by one and convert it into a list of ints, is there a way to convert each character into a new list?

```
["123","346","789"] to [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

stringToInt :: [String] -> [[Int]]
```

Comment: [123. 346, 789] is not a list of strings. Do you mean [“123”, “346”, “789”]? Or do you want to split the numbers into figures?

Comment: yes that's what I mean sorry

Comment: What do you want the function to return if I pass in `["1xt3"]`?

Comment: I just want to assume that all strings will be valid ints once converted

Comment: Since this sounds like homework, I’ll give you only an hint which applies if this is not the case. Since strings can also contain things that are not numbers, any function of type [String] -> [[Int]] has to be partial, so I would suggest you to implement instead a function of type [String] -> Maybe [[Int]] or [String] -> [Maybe [Int]] or [String] -> [[Maybe Int]], depending on what’s the intended usage.

Comment: `map (map digitToInt)` using `Data.Char`

Comment: Show us your attempt so we could help you.

Comment: `[ [ (fromEnum d) - 48 | d <- e] | e <- ["123","346","789"]]`

Answer (score 1):

One of the pillars of functional programming is `map`, which has the following signature:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In other words, it takes a function that expects a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `b` (N.B. these could be the same type, but don't have to be) along with a list of `a` values, and kicks you back a list of `b` values. Take this example:

```
double :: Int -> Int
double = (*2)
{- equivalently written as:
   double x = x * 2 -}

as = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
bs = map double as
```

In this example, map is specialized where `a ~ Int` and `b ~ Int`, resolving to

```
map :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

and `bs` is then `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]`.

---

Why this long primer on `map`? Because it's the framework to so many answers in functional programming, including your question. Remember that `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]`, so you're trying to go from `[[Char]] -> [[Int]]`. Gee, that sure looks like the last two terms of the type signature for map, doesn't it? Let's specialize `map` to operate in these terms.

```
map :: ([Char] -> [Int]) -> [[Char]] -> [[Int]]
```

But wait, the function that `map` is expecting *also* looks like the result of a mapping. Let's write that, too.

```
map :: (Char -> Int) -> [Char] -> [Int]
```

So what we want is a *double* map, applied to some function `f` such that:

```
map (map f) :: [[Char]] -> [[Int]]
{- more idiomatically written as
   (map . map) f :: [[Char]] -> [[Int]] -}
```

This means we need an `f :: Char -> Int` -- some function that goes from single characters to integers. There's a reasonably small number of defined inputs for that operation, so I'd just write it.

```
digitToInt :: Char -> Int
digitToInt '0' = 0
digitToInt '1' = 1
digitToInt '2' = 2
digitToInt '3' = 3
digitToInt '4' = 4
digitToInt '5' = 5
digitToInt '6' = 6
digitToInt '7' = 7
digitToInt '8' = 8
digitToInt '9' = 9
digitToInt 'a' = 10
digitToInt 'A' = 10
digitToInt 'b' = 11
digitToInt 'B' = 11
digitToInt 'c' = 12
digitToInt 'C' = 12
digitToInt 'd' = 13
digitToInt 'D' = 13
digitToInt 'e' = 14
digitToInt 'E' = 14
digitToInt 'f' = 15
digitToInt 'F' = 15
digitToInt _   = error "Invalid digit"
```

but N.B. that this function comes standard in `Data.Char`

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
```

Your result then is:

```
result = (map.map) digitToInt ["123","346","789"]
```

Comment: Note that `digitToInt` isn't a great function here because it is not *total*, as alluded to in the comments on your question, and also when I wrote "There's a reasonably small number of defined inputs for that operation." Any time the domain for a type is larger than the number of inputs you can define your function for, you're probably not writing the most idiomatic Haskell code. In this case, it would be better if you wrote `digitToMaybeInt :: Char -> Maybe Int` and made `result :: [[Maybe Int]]` (or even `[Maybe [Int]]` or `Maybe [[Int]]` depending on your strictness.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

f :: String :: [Int]
f stringnum = read $ "[" ++ intersperse  ',' stringnum ++ "]" :: [Int]

>>> map f ["123", "456"]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```